# Turn on Nokia 625 without power button

Tags: 8.1, nokia-lumia-625

Last day my phone (Nokia Lumia 625H) power button is broken somehow. This morning when i open instagram in my phone, it suddenly crash and turnde off. How can i turn on my phone ?

Comment: It doesn't respond to the power button at all? Have you tried charging it? Perhaps the battery simply died.

Comment: can you remove broken power button and stick some thin metal istead power button?